# ReactRouter 2.0.1 context missing with links

Tags: javascript, react-router

I am using `react-router` version `2.0.1` with following file:

```
import React, {Component}              from 'react'
import {render}                        from 'react-dom'
import {Link, Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router'

class Home extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Home</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

class About extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>About</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

class Contact extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Contact</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

render(
  <section>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
    </Router>,
  </section>,
  document.querySelector('main')
)
```

When I click on one of the links, I get:

```
ReactErrorUtils.js:71 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
handleClick @   Link.js:124
ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback   @   ReactErrorUtils.js:71
executeDispatch @   EventPluginUtils.js:79
executeDispatchesInOrder    @   EventPluginUtils.js:102
executeDispatchesAndRelease @   EventPluginHub.js:43
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @   EventPluginHub.js:54
forEachAccumulated  @   forEachAccumulated.js:23
processEventQueue   @   EventPluginHub.js:259
runEventQueueInBatch    @   ReactEventEmitterMixin.js:18
handleTopLevel  @   ReactEventEmitterMixin.js:34
handleTopLevelWithoutPath   @   ReactEventListener.js:93
handleTopLevelImpl  @   ReactEventListener.js:73
perform @   Transaction.js:136
batchedUpdates  @   ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates  @   ReactUpdates.js:94
dispatchEvent   @   ReactEventListener.js:204
```

with `Link.js:124`:

```
this.context.router.push(_location);
```

Any idea what I am missing?

**Edit:** To find full example you can clone this [gist](http://gist.github.com/bodokaiser/8482e0932fe242967c8f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.context.router.push is the function that is failing.

So either the router property isn't being set on the context object or context isn't being passed....

I see that you put Link components as peers (not children) of the Router component.

context (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) is passed down the component tree and I'm guessing that because the Links are outside that, they are not able to find the appropriate context.

Try rewriting the app component tree

Comment: Ah yes I need to place every `Link` inside the `<Route path="/" component={App}></Route` such that context is passed!